# Axios config default GET param

Tags: vue.js, axios

I'm using Axios in my VueJS application and I want to add a default GET param in my request. I send my API-KEY through the URL `?api-key=secret` and I don't want to specify this parameter each time.

I see in the documentation that we can set [Global custom defaults](https://github.com/axios/axios#global-axios-defaults). With that we don't have to specify the header each time. But can we do the same for get param ?

Comment: Do you want to add it to the headers or just to every get request?

Comment: @Taylor every requests. Not inside the header

Comment: Marcelo's answer should work or you could use interceptors which works like middleware

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Here it is:

```
axios.defaults.params = {}
axios.defaults.params['api-key'] = secret
```

Comment: It will not be replaced by the other get param when I'll use axios ?

Comment: No, it will keep the default params and append the other ones you pass.

Comment: Ok thanks, I'll check that tomorrow and I'll accept the answer

Comment: For some reason, axios.defaults.params['api-key'] = secret didn't work for me, however, the former did.

Answer (score 33):

I struggled to get this to work with axios instances using the two most commonly suggested methods:

```js
// method 1: setting axios.defaults.params at the class level
axios.defaults.params = {}
axios.defaults.params['api-key'] = secret
```

and

```js
// method 2: setting the `params` attribute at an instance level
const axClient = axios.create({
    baseURL: process.env.VUE_APP_BASE_URL,
    params: {
        api-key: process.env.VUE_APP_API_KEY
    }
});
```

I did however, manage to get it working nicely using interceptors like this:

```js
// create an instance with default properties
const axClient = axios.create({
    baseURL: process.env.VUE_APP_BASE_URL,
});

axClient.interceptors.request.use((config) => {
    // use config.params if it has been set
    config.params = config.params || {};
    // add any client instance specific params to config
    config.params['api-key'] = process.env.VUE_APP_API_KEY;
    return config;
});
```

The benefit of this approach is that the instance level params can be dynamic/computed per request if needed.

As a (slightly contrived) example, if you needed to add a JWT to each request (including any logic to fetch it from your storage method of choice) and even react to the logic around that. So in this toy example, if the user doesn't have a JWT in storage, redirect them to the login page instead of making the request.

Comment: This is the best solution, in case you are using multiple APIs to connect to. In my case I have several `axios.create's` and the interceptor makes totatlly sense to me :) Great solution!

Comment: What should one do if I want to delete the `api-key` param from config?

Comment: @EddChang how do you mean?

Answer (score 2):

If you need to call a function before each axios request, you should use an interceptor.

Comment: Why use interceptor instead of default ?

Comment: Maybe you need to check the users token before appending the secret

Comment: Hey Félix, this would be a great comment for the OP. But it is not a good answer. For a good answer you'll need to specify your "solution". Just saying "hey, dude read the docs" does not help really. Sure, there are interceptors, but could you provide an example, please? Otherwise the OP will open the next question: "What is an interceptor?" And that's what we are trying constantly to avoid.